# Sort a HashMap using it key to add its corresponding value

Tags: java, collections

I am having a List that has following values.
value   : Key
1000    :34
300000  :34
300000  :35
300000  :36
300000  :37
20000   :38
2000    :34
Now i want to add the values that has similar key. In the above example it would 
be , the key 34 is occurred multiple  times, I want to add the values with similar keys. the List would be
1000+30000+2000 =303000
Final list
303000=34
300000  :35
300000  :36
300000  :37
20000   :38
Thank you.

Comment: It is impossible to have entries with the same key in a HashMap

Comment: I never ended up having same key in hashmap.

Comment: Code would definitely be needed, as others have said the whole point of a HashMap is that you have a singular instance of any given key.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible for a map to have the same keys twice. But if you want to populate a map as you described you want to check if the key already is in the map, if it isn't you simply put the value, and if it is you add the current and the new value and put the sum into the map

Something like this:

```
int key = (...);
int value = (...);

map.put(key, map.get(key) == null ? value : map.get(key) + value);
```

Comment: Consider: `map.put(key, value + (map.containsKey(key) ? map.get(key) : 0));`. `containsKey()` is safer than comparing get() with null,  and this code mentions `value` just once.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me... i checked for the available key using containsKey()  and then added the value..!!